# Porque não consigo centralizar imagem usando 'text-align:center'?

Tags: html5, css3

Segue o código abaixo:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:400px">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="image" width="300" src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #image {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Aqui está um exemplo em [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28240/)

Com comando `<center></center>` funciona, mais muita gente não recomenda.

Comment: Não faz sentido aplicar o align na imagem. aplique na div de fora dela.

Comment: Verdade @Bacco, valeu, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: O problema foi aplicar aling na imagem, mais agora foi resolvida moçada

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando centralizar o conteúdo da imagem. Para funcionar o `text-align:center`, ele teria que ser aplicado na `div` onde a imagem se encontra. Mas também nao é o caminho.

O melhor é definir a imagem com `display:block` e colocar margem automática:

```css
#image {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:400px">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="image" width="300" src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

(apesar do senso comum, a imagem é normalmente implementada como `inline-block` e não como `block`)

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa aplicar o `text-align` na div `panel-body` e não na imagem.

Answer (score 4):

```css
#image {  
  display: table;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" style="width:500px; border:1px solid">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="image" width="300" src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```